# Constrain array values to an allowed set of values

Tags: postgresql, array, check-constraints

I would like to set up a CHECK constraint that makes sure that a `text[]` column's elements contain only certain values.

Setting up an example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
  countries text[]
);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('{"Morocco", "Mali", "Indonesia"}');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('{"Sokovia", "Mali"}');
```

Now only "Morocco", "Mali" and "Indonesia" should be allowed, so the second row should get rejected by the constraint.

I have a "working" solution:

```
CHECK (array_length(
  array_remove(
    array_remove(
      array_remove(
        countries,
        'Indonesia'
      ), 'Mali'
    ), 'Morocco'
  ), 1) IS NULL)
```

But this is not very readable.

I tried this as well:

```
CHECK ((
  SELECT unnest(countries)
  EXCEPT
  SELECT unnest(array['Morocco', 'Mali', 'Indonesia'])
) IS NULL)
```

but:

> ERROR cannot use subquery in check constraint

Comment: This is not what arrays should be used for. Create a proper 1-to-many relationship with a foreign key.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I could also use an array of ENUMs. I'm interested if there is a nice way to do it with text[] and CHECK, though, because it's kind of a useful skill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the “is contained in” operator in your check constraint:

```
CHECK (countries <@ ARRAY['Morocco', 'Mali', 'Indonesia'])
```